# What does it mean for a quantum particle to have energy $E_n$? And what is its general normalised state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, hilbert-space, hamiltonian

In this particular case, I have found the energy to be quantised with energy levels $\frac{h^2n^2}{2m} >0 $ where $n$ is an integer.

Suppose a particle has energy $E=\frac{4h^2}{2m}$, then this clearly corresponds to $n=2$ or -2.

Now, what is the general normalised state of a particle when it has this energy?

(What does it mean for the particle to "have this energy"? That $H\psi=E\psi$, where $H$ is the Hamiltonian?)

Clearly a linear combination of the eigenstates corresponding to $n=2$ and $-2$ will give $H\psi=E\psi$. However, does the general state only involve these or is it a sum of all other eigenstates too? If the latter, how do we find the co-efficients?

Comment: Note that $n$ starts from zero and cannot be negative. Assuming that you got this answer by calculating energy eigenstates, then it means that the particle remains with that energy, hence the term stationary states.

Comment: *Which* particular case? And there is something missing from your expression for the energy; it is not dimensionally consistent (perhaps a factor of $\frac{1}{4L^2}$ for a particle in a box of length $L$?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A state $\psi$ corresponds to an energy $E$ if:
$$H\psi = E\psi$$

Clearly, if there is a state $\psi = \sum_i c_i \psi_i$ where $H\psi_i = E_0\psi_i\ \forall i$, then
$$H\psi = \sum_i c_i H\psi_i = \sum_i c_i E_0\psi_i = E_0\psi$$
A linear combination of states with the same energy value again has the same energy value.

Now consider $\psi = c_1\psi_1 + c_2\psi_2$, with $H\psi_1 = E_1\psi_1$, $H\psi_2 = E_2\psi_2$, where $E_1 \ne E_2$, so that
$$H\psi = c_1H\psi_1 + c_2H\psi_2 = E_1c_1\psi_1 + E_2c_2\psi_2$$
In general, the right hand side reduces to (say) $E\psi$ only if $E_1 = E_2 = E$, or either of $c_1$ or $c_2$ equal zero. Thus, a linear combination of states with different energy values is not an energy eigenstate at all.

In general, if you know a state $\psi$ (say as a function $\psi(x)$ in the position representation), and you want to express it as $\psi = \sum_nc_n\psi_n$, where the $\psi_n$ are normalized energy eigenstates (more generally, normalized eigenstates of any Hermitian operator) then the $c_n$ can be found by making use of the following "[orthonormality](http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node140.html)" relations:
$$\int dx\ \psi_m^*\psi_n = \delta_{mn}$$
where $\delta_{mn}$ is the [Kronecker delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), which is $1$ when $m = n$ and zero otherwise.
Using this, we multiply $\psi$ by $\psi_m^*$ for some $m$, and integrate to get:
$$c_m = \int dx\ \psi_m^* \psi$$
With both $\psi_m$ and $\psi$ known, the integral (in principle) gives the coefficients of the linear combination.